# Avoid quote autocomplete in sublime text when backslash is inserted

Tags: autocomplete, latex, sublimetext, diacritics, quote

I am writing a latex document and I want to insert accented characters..

Suppose I want to insert accented e: `è`

If I want to write it I use:

```
\`e
```

But with sublime autocomplete, when I insert the backquote I get

```
\`e`
```

So I have to delete the extra backquote each time I insert an accented character.. Is there a way to avoid closing quote if the first quote is preceded by a backslash?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following to your user key bindings.

```
{ "keys": ["'"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "'"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\)|]|\\}|>|$)", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "['a-zA-Z0-9_]$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "eol_selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "string.quoted.single", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\\\$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex", "match_all": true }
    ]
}
```

I took the existing key binding for auto pairing quotes in the default key bindings. I then changed the snippet so it would simply enter a single character. You could change it to an `insert` command but it doesn't really matter. I then added the last 2 entries to context. The first checks the preceding text for `\`. The second restricts the key binding to files that have a scope of `text.tex.latex`. The second entry isn't really necessary, but if it's not there, it will apply to all file types, not just `tex` files.

**edit**

Double quote solution

```
{ "keys": ["\""], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\""}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\)|]|\\}|>|$)", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "[\"a-zA-Z0-9_]$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "eol_selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "string.quoted.double", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\\\$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex", "match_all": true }
    ]
}
```

To reiterate, I started with the double quote auto pair key binding (from the defaults), and added the two context entries. Failing to parse means you had some malformed json. If I had to guess, you had to many/not enough `\` escapes.

**edit2**

Same procedure. Hopefully I got the right quote this time :)

```
{ "keys": ["`"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "`"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex"},
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\\\$", "match_all": true }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It does work.. :) I don't get why it works with backquote putting quote, and I am trying to make it work with normal quote too..

Comment: To get it to work with a normal quote, replace the `'` in keys and contents with `"`.  It works because when you press `'` in this case, it is running a command. That command is saying to enter a single quote. The default binding is to enter the paired quote.

Comment: It doesn't work.. It fails to parse.. can you please add it to your answer? I tried also with `\"` but it does not work..

Comment: Sorry @skuroda but for me it does not work :( moreover for quote I intended single quote `'` ... I tried with backslash and without it in `keys` but I cannot manage to make it work.. any clue? Thanks

Comment: Ah you know what, I misread/misunderstood, though you were working with regular quotes, not backticks.  ST doesn't do the auto pairing. What plugins are you using to work with latex? You'll do something similar. Take a look at the key map files these plugins give you. You can probably figure out the solution from there. If not, please post the plugins you are using.

Comment: Maybe I found it http://pastebin.com/gUUPeukS .. the package is latextools.. Maybe if I overwrite this setting I can get rid of autopairing..

Comment: Okay then, updated again. Hopefully I got the correct quote this time (make sure these go in your User key bindings).